# How to get the exact number of rows in webtable in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

[image: screen shot for the number of rows]

How to get the exact number of rows in webtable using xpath in webdriver using Java. Using the below xpath i am able to the count with header also. I don't want the count to include the header row and get the count of a webtable.

```
//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GrdHistory']/tbody/tr
```

HTML Code:

```
<table id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GrdHistory" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="color:#333333;width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr style="color:Black;background-color:#DFC065;font-weight:bold;">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;"   onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$0')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$1')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$2')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$3')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$4')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$5')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$6')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$7')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$8')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;"  onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$9')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$10')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$11')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$12')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(251, 247, 234); text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$13')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color:#FBF7EA;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$14')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color:#FBF7EA;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GrdHistory','Select$15')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
```

Is this possible, if so then how do i get the count without including the header row in the count. Please help me on this. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below xpath to exclude first row (Headers)

```
//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GrdHistory']/tbody/tr[position()>1]
```

Comment: Thanks Santoshsarma for your reply. But the code does not work for me. It is giving the same count as before.

Comment: It should work Umamaheshwar. just try with >2 I think you understood how that position() method will work in xpath.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest :

```
 count(table[@id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GrdHistory"]/tbody/tr) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int count = (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GrdHistory']/tbody/tr")).size()) - 1;
```